# Select the first rows of a table (that has a column with int values which sum of values is less than the input

Tags: mysql, sql, database

My input is `5` in this case, and I want to select the first two rows, to delete the first row and to update the second one, putting the value `7` instead of `10`.

[image]

I tried to do this query but it's not enough:

```
SELECT SUM(`Qty in acquisto`) AS total,`Prezzo in acquisto` 
FROM `book` 
GROUP BY `Qty in acquisto` 
HAVING COUNT(*) >5
```

Comment: Does your table have an id or anything you can use to order by so you know which record is first, second, ...

Comment: sure, the 'Qty in acquisto' is the name of the first column, and 'Prezzo in acquisto' is the name of the second column. But i need to order by 'Prezzo     in acquisto' in descending order,in the way to let the highest price in top of the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use variables to get the rows of interest, together with the information you need to update the records:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
    SELECT   `Qty in acquisto`,
             `Prezzo in acquisto`,
             @take := least(`Qty in acquisto`, @needed) as taken,
             `Qty in acquisto` - @take as adjusted_acquisto, 
             @needed := @needed - @take as still_needed
    FROM     book,
             (select @needed := 5) as init
    ORDER BY `Prezzo in acquisto` DESC) base
WHERE  taken + still_needed > 0
```

The output for the sample data is:

```
| Qty in acquisto | Prezzo in acquisto | taken | adjusted_acquisto | still_needed |
|-----------------|--------------------|-------|-------------------|--------------|
|               2 |               1000 |     2 |                 0 |            3 |
|              10 |                960 |     3 |                 7 |            0 |
```

See [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7c6388/2)

In the innermost query, with alias *init*, you pass the number of books you need (5 in the example).

So in column `adjusted_acquisto` you find the value you need to perform the deletes and update:

If that value is 0, delete the corresponding record.

It that value is not 0, update the Qty with that value.

Answer (score 1):

E.g.:

```
 SELECT * FROM my_table;
+------+--------+
| id   | amount |
+------+--------+
|  800 |      8 |
|  900 |      3 |
|  950 |      4 |
|  960 |     10 |
| 1000 |      2 |
+------+--------+
SELECT n.id
     , GREATEST(amount-@x,0) new_amount
     , @x:=GREATEST(@x-amount,0) x 
  FROM my_table n
     , (SELECT @x:=5) vars 
 ORDER 
    BY id DESC;
+------+--------+------------+------+
| id   | amount | new_amount | x    |
+------+--------+------------+------+
| 1000 |      2 |          0 |    3 |
|  960 |     10 |          7 |    0 |
|  950 |      4 |          4 |    0 |
|  900 |      3 |          3 |    0 |
|  800 |      8 |          8 |    0 |
+------+--------+------------+------+
```